# i am changing blockuserinfo module in prestahop but nothing is happening

Tags: module, prestashop-1.6

I started using Prestashop before 2 3 daysso I’m a total beginner, but I've got some questions.

```
1.i want to change button name but when i am done changes in blockuser.tpl and nothing is change i am removing cache also but no output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing core file of module.

There must be tpl file inside your theme folder. Change file on below mentioned path;

```
themes\{YOUR_THEME}\modules\blockuserinfo\blockuserinfo.tpl
```

Do your changes and clear cache and then check.

Comment: Thanks @Divyesh prajpati :)